# Azure function not deploying when importing azure.search.documents (time trigger)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to deploy a simple time-triggered function in my azure subscription. The `__init__.py` code us basically the template. However, I am encountering issues when deploying the function only when importing (not even using) one module/library. The line causing the problem is:

- `from azure.search.documents import SearchClient`

So, the code that is correctly deployed and triggered:

```
import os
import sys
from io import StringIO
import csv
import time
import json  
import openai
import logging
import requests
from dateutil import parser
from dotenv   import load_dotenv  
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,ContainerClient,BlobClient
from tenacity import retry, wait_random_exponential, stop_after_attempt  
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential  
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

#from azure.search.documents import SearchClient  

import datetime
import azure.functions as func

from . import util_codes_custom as ucc

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
    logging.info(ucc.print_message("keyvault?"))
```

When deployed, azure monitor shows all blue lines like:

```
2023-08-11T17:33:00Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id: 'fa46dc97-ab44-4732-xxxx-65d165d76a17
2023-08-11T17:33:00Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:fa46dc97-ab44-4732-xxxx-65d165d76a17 on workerId:dc4b5bc9-d9c4-403d-a51f-5b72c86eaf2a
2023-08-11T17:33:00Z   [Information]   Python timer trigger function ran at 2023-08-11T17:33:00.004288+00:00
2023-08-11T17:33:00Z   [Information]   keyvault?
2023-08-11T17:33:00Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.azurefunction-minutas-timetrigger' (Succeeded, Id=fa46dc97-ab44-4732-b0aa-65d165d76a17, Duration=19ms)
2023-08-11T17:33:20Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.azurefunction-minutas-timetrigger' (Reason='Timer fired at 2023-08-11T17:33:20.0002929+00:00', Id=3c23fc7a-a0d3-4e42-9b0f-b4c103ba3bba)
```

The moment I uncomment the `azure.search.documents` import line the function fail and give the following log messages in the monitor (when deployed):

```
2023-08-11T18:15:20Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id: '096b7468-e0ba-4641-8562-d85779b551f3
2023-08-11T18:15:20Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:096b7468-e0ba-4641-XXXX-d85779b551f3 on workerId:b4c17b5d-53c6-4455-bfa8-d01f322a28b0
2023-08-11T18:15:20Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.azurefunction-minutas-timetrigger' (Failed, Id=096b7468-e0ba-4641-8562-d85779b551f3, Duration=20ms)
```

My pip list (what's installed on .venv) is:

```
Package                     Version
--------------------------- ------------------
aiohttp                     3.8.5
aiosignal                   1.3.1
async-timeout               4.0.3
attrs                       23.1.0
azure-ai-formrecognizer     3.2.1
azure-common                1.1.28
azure-core                  1.27.1
azure-functions             1.15.0
azure-identity              1.13.0
azure-keyvault              4.2.0
azure-keyvault-certificates 4.7.0
azure-keyvault-keys         4.8.0
azure-keyvault-secrets      4.7.0
azure-search-documents      11.4.0a20230509004
azure-storage-blob          12.16.0
certifi                     2023.7.22
cffi                        1.15.1
charset-normalizer          3.2.0
colorama                    0.4.6
cryptography                41.0.3
frozenlist                  1.4.0
idna                        3.4
isodate                     0.6.1
msal                        1.23.0
msal-extensions             1.0.0
msrest                      0.7.1
multidict                   6.0.4
numpy                       1.25.1
oauthlib                    3.2.2
openai                      0.27.8
pip                         23.2.1
portalocker                 2.7.0
pycparser                   2.21
PyJWT                       2.8.0
python-dateutil             2.8.2
python-dotenv               1.0.0
pywin32                     306
requests                    2.31.0
requests-oauthlib           1.3.1
setuptools                  65.5.0
six                         1.16.0
tenacity                    8.2.2
tqdm                        4.66.1
typing_extensions           4.7.1
urllib3                     2.0.4
yarl                        1.9.2
```

Note that the version of `azure.search.documents` is not a standard one. It is installed in the requirement.txt as:

```
-i https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/azure-sdk/public/_packaging/azure-sdk-for-python/pypi/simple/
azure-search-documents==11.4.0a20230509004
```

What can be going wrong? I read something about "dockerizing" the function. Is this the only solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the **from azure.search.documents import SearchClient** to **azure-search-documents==11.4.0b8**, I can able to import it and able to run a simple code with it.

**Code:**

```py
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func

from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    search_service_name = '<search_name>'
    index_name = '<index_name>'
    admin_key = '<search_key>'

    endpoint = f"https://<>search_name.search.windows.net/"
    credential = AzureKeyCredential(admin_key)
    search_client = SearchClient(endpoint=endpoint, index_name=index_name, credential=credential)

    results = search_client.search(search_text="<search_query>")
    for result in results:
        logging.info(f"Search result: {result}")

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**requiremets.txt:**

```py
azure-core==1.27.1
azure-functions==1.15.0
azure-identity==1.13.0
azure-search-documents==11.4.0b8
```

**Output:**

The Azure functions Timer trigger runs successfully as below,

[image]
[image]

Then, I deployed this to the function app and it got deployed successfully like below,

[image]

I run the functions code in the function app at Azure Portal and it runs successfully as below,

[image]

Comment: @GEBRU I just tried this in debug mode.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I have no problem at any point in the code. The problem appears when deployed to the Azure portal. Maybe the question is why is there such a difference in behavior, right?

Comment: @GEBRU Ok, I will deploy it and let you know.

Comment: @GEBRU I deployed my code to the function app and updated my answer. Can you check it once?

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot! however, it seems like there is something with the documents library that breaks the process. It is still not working when installing  11.4.0a20230509004 version...